# Animating an svg with snap

Tags: javascript, html, svg, snap.svg

I've look at loads of blog posts about snap.svg, all discuss how to draw and animate. None have information about animating an existing svg.

How can I animate an existing svg? How do I need to include it in the page?

Can I just use  or will I need to use

Does anyone have an example of using an existing svg and animating it?

Please note, I do not want to include the svg source code in the page but link to the file itself.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you cannot animate an svg *image*, so if you try animating an svg img tag, it won't work.

The main 2 options (if you can't include inline, which is normally fine) with an svg file are

1) Load the svg in via javascript, insert into the DOM and animate

2) Have the HTML link to an object tag and reference that (as an object tag has a DOM, so can be animated)

**Method** 1) (load in svg file, add to existing base svg element or create one)

```
var s = Snap('#mySvg');

var tux = Snap.load("Dreaming_tux.svg", function ( loadedFragment ) {
               s.append( loadedFragment );
               s.hover( hoverover, hoverout );
               otherAnimationFuncstuff();
} );

// add hover funcs, all DOM selections will now work. Make sure selects happen 
// AFTER the load callback has finished
// Note, a base SVG element must exist, or you can add one with Snap(width,height)
```

[example](http://svg.dabbles.info/snaptut-load-animate)

**Method 2)** (referencing an object tag)

```
//html
<object id="svgobject" data="Dreaming_Tux.svg"></object>
```

We reference the object document using **contentDocument**

```
var mySvg = document.getElementById("svgobject").contentDocument.getElementById("tux");
```

We 'Snapify' the object, ie create a snap variable that can access it.

```
var s = Snap( mySvg );
```

We can then animate it, by selecting some element from it, eg

```
var g = s.select("#g30")
         .animate({ transform: 'r360,150,150s1.3' }, 1000, mina.bounce );
```

[example](http://svg.dabbles.info/snapobject.html)

I'm not such a fan of the object method 2, as I think its likely more prone to inconsistencies across browsers, and I suspect performance may not be quite so good, but I may be wrong.

I tend to think its more optimal to include the source inline (which you don't want, but not sure why), or pull it in as example 1.

Comment: Thanks, with method 2, "mySvg = document.getElementById("svgobject").contentDocument.getElementById("tux");" what is "tux"?

Comment: tux is just the id of an element within the svg image/object itself we want to animate, so we may want to animate the whole thing, or may want to animate his eyes or whatever. Basically anything you can normally select in the DOM, it doesn't have to specifically be getElementById I guess, but its quite common to do that..

Comment: But then what is: var g = s.select("#g30")? I have an svg object with id of 'svgobject' I wish to animate a cloud with id 'cloud-1', how can I access it?

Comment: its just selecting another element id from within the Snap svg s. Its just we initially got a reference to the svg, to save having to keep traversing through the whole DOM every time we want to find an element, you could initially just grab g30. You don't have to do this, it depends how often you are repeating the same code as to whether its worth it or not. You could use document.getElementById("svgobject").contentDocument.getElementById("g30"); but its a lot of code to keep typing if more than once.

Comment: So could I not just use: var mySvg = document.getElementById("svgobject");var s = Snap( mySvg );var g = s.select("#cloud-1")

Comment: No, you can't use document.getElementById (you could if it was inline svg), as the 'object' is in a different document space, you would need to use contentDocument on the object element to access this. You could probably do something like.... Snap(document.getElementById("svgobject").contentDocument.getElementById('#cloud-1')).animate(.....) but you need to reference the contentDocument to indicate its in the object space. Hence why it makes sense to have a variable referencing that.